# SQLite database query with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, sqlite-net

Trying to develop a Windows 8.1 Store App.  Amongst other difficulties, I need to retrieve records from a sqlite database with two parameters on the where clause.  I can successfully query with one parameter in the where clause but it crashes everything when I try to use two parameters.  Here is my code for this:

```
    public string SaveMaint(MaintViewModel Maintenance)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
        {
            string change = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var existingmaintenance = db.Query<maintenance> ("select * from maintenance where VehID = ? AND MaintID = ?", new String[] {Maintenance.Maintid, Maintenance.Vehicleid});
               // var existingmaintenance = (db.Table<maintenance>().Where 
               //     (c => c.MaintID == Maintenance.Maintid).SingleOrDefault());

                if (existingmaintenance != null)
                {
                    existingmaintenance.VehID = Maintenance.Vehicleid;
                    existingmaintenance.MaintID = Maintenance.Maintid; 
                    existingmaintenance.ServiceDate = Maintenance.Servicedate;
                    existingmaintenance.ServiceCost = Maintenance.Servicecost;
                    existingmaintenance.ServiceLocation = Maintenance.Servicelocation;
                    existingmaintenance.ServiceNote = Maintenance.Servicenote;
                    existingmaintenance.ServiceOdom = Maintenance.Serviceodom;
                    int success = db.Update(existingmaintenance);
                }
                else
                {
                    int success = db.Insert(new maintenance()
                    {
                        VehID = Maintenance.Vehicleid,
                        MaintID = Maintenance.Maintid,
                        ServiceDate = Maintenance.Servicedate,
                        ServiceCost = Maintenance.Servicecost,
                        ServiceLocation = Maintenance.Servicelocation,
                        ServiceNote = Maintenance.Servicenote,
                        ServiceOdom = Maintenance.Serviceodom
                    });
                }
                result = "Success";
            }
            catch
            {
                result = "This project was not saved.";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Please refer to the line in which `existingmaintenance` variable is defined.  The commented out version of this line works fine.  When I substitute the variable definition with the two parameter query (obtained using a different method because I couldn't figure out how to add a second parameter to the Table query approach), it crashes.

Thanks for any help you can give.  Sorry that I only half understand what I'm doing.

Comment: What kind of ORM are you using? It seems to be Dapper with Extension but I am not sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) as your ORM, you can just pass in the parameters after the query. As far as I know there is no support for anonymous classes, as in your example. Try this:

```
var existingmaintenance = db.Query<maintenance>(
    "select * from maintenance where VehID = ? AND MaintID = ?",
    Maintenance.Vehicleid, Maintenance.Maintid).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can also use a linq query, like so:

```
var existingmaintenance = db.Table<maintenance>().Where 
    (c => c.VehID == Maintenance.Vehicleid && 
    c.MaintID == Maintenance.Maintid).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am using sqlite-net.  I thought I tried every possible way to do a query like your second suggestion and I failed.  But yours worked like a charm!  Thank you so much!  I was not putting the "FirstOrDefault()" part on it.  Can I do something to give you some points for this?  I just clicked the check mark.  I don't have enough hutspa to give your answer a vote up, apparently.

Comment: @user3798080, accepting my answer gives me points. Upvoting also would give me points but as you say, you don't have enough "hutspa" yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I hope both Id are int in database

```
var existingmaintenance = db.Query<maintenance> ("select * from maintenance where VehID = " + Maintenance.Maintid  + " AND MaintID = " + Maintenance.Vehicleid ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Ashish.  Chue answer did the trick so I didn't need to try yours.